# Is there a way to automatically retreive Azure Resource Naming restriction

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm working on a method/program that will automatically name resources according to restrictions and recommended abbrevation.

At the moment I add the restrictions in a table but it's alot of labor and annoying to maintain. Are there an API I'm missing that would allow me to retreive naming restrictions for resources in Azure?

Currently I'm using below docs:

[Naming rules and restrictions for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules)
[Recommended abbreviations for Azure resource types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/resource-abbreviations)

Comment: You can use this [Azure naming tool](https://github.com/microsoft/CloudAdoptionFramework/tree/master/ready/AzNamingTool) and also you can run this as an standalone container on your local machine that is running with docker or  [deploy it](https://github.com/microsoft/CloudAdoptionFramework/blob/master/ready/AzNamingTool/INSTALLATION.md) on azure app service container as well.

Comment: Thanks! I can definitely work with that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding as an answer from our comment discussion, We don't have any REST API to pull the resource naming restriction and recommended abbreviations.

Alternatively,You can use this [Azure naming tool](https://github.com/microsoft/CloudAdoptionFramework/tree/master/ready/AzNamingTool) and also you can run this as a standalone container on your local machine that is running with docker or [deploy it](https://github.com/microsoft/CloudAdoptionFramework/blob/master/ready/AzNamingTool/INSTALLATION.md) on azure app service container as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to VenkateshDodda-MSFT:s comment i managed to find this file:
[AzNamingTool/repository/resourcetypes.json](https://github.com/microsoft/CloudAdoptionFramework/blob/master/ready/AzNamingTool/repository/resourcetypes.json)

This contains what I was searching for. All the rules in one file that I can use to build my logic around.

Thanks!